# Retrieve all posts and their most recent comments in 1 query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I'm trying to retrieve a (paginated) list of posts and include their most recent comments in one Eloquent query statement. Posts and comments are connected by a one to many relationship.

This was my attempt:

```
Post::with(['comments' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->take(3);
}])->simplePaginate(15);
```

But that only retrieves **3 comments in total**, not 3 comments per post.

Comment: I don't think laravel allows you to limit eager loaded relationships. I would suggest iterating over the post array and load the comments for example: 

$posts = Post::simplePaginate(15); foreach($posts as post) { $post->load(['comments' => function($query) { $query->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->take(3);}])'

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

It seems you can not do it with 1 query.
You still can have this function in the parent model, called "lastComments":

```
function lastComments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post', 'post_id')->orderBy('created_at')->take(3);
}
```

You load posts with normal eloquent code:

```
Post::simplePaginate(15);
```

And in the view page you show the comments in this way:

```
@foreach($post->lastComments as $comment)
    <!-- ... -->
@endforeach
```

Comment: As far as I can see that produces the same result, only 3 comments in total are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Joined table Id is necessary
Try this:

```
 Post::with(array('comments'=>function($query){
            $query->select('id as commentid','comment')->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->take(3);
        }))->simplePaginate(15);
```

Comment: This did not produce any results for me. What is the use of the second argument for the select function ('comment')?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `$with` variable in your `App\Post` model:

```
protected $with = ['lastComments'];
```

This way whenever you fetch a post, Laravel will automatically load the comments for it.